# Generic integral for n-th order gaussian

Tags: gaussian-integral, gaussian

I'm working with [super-gaussian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_function#Higher-order_Gaussian_or_super-Gaussian_function) profiles of the form:

$$
f(x) = A\exp\bigg({-\big(\frac{(x-x_0)^2}{2\sigma^2}\big)}^n\bigg)
$$

I need to integrate this function for various $n$ values (probably between 4-30), and was wondering if there's a more modular way to do this that applies to all $n$, rather than having to derive an integral for every value of $n$ that I choose?

Edit: The limits of integration are finite (between -0.3 and 0.3 for all $n$)

Answer (score 2):

Using centered-reduced coordinates, the integration limits are arbitrary and

$$\int_a^b e^{-u^{2n}}du=\frac1{2n}\int_a^b t^{-1+1/2n}e^{-t}dt$$

which is an incomplete Gamma integral.

Answer (score 2):

$$I_n=\int\exp\left({-\left(\frac{(x-x_0)^2}{2 \sigma ^2}\right)^n}\right)\,dx=\frac{\sigma }{\sqrt{2}}\int \frac{e^{-t^n}}{\sqrt{t}}\,dt=-\frac{\sigma  }{\sqrt{2} n}\Gamma \left(\frac{1}{2 n},t^n\right)$$

**Edit**

Using $x_0=0$ and $\sigma=1$ the integral between $0$ and $\infty$ is given by
$$S_\infty=\sqrt{2}\,\, \Gamma \left(1+\frac{1}{2 n}\right)$$ while the integral between $0$ and $a$ is given by
$$S_a=\frac{\Gamma \left(\frac{1}{2 n}\right)-\Gamma \left(\frac{1}{2 n},2^{-n} a^{2n}\right)}{\sqrt{2} n}$$ So, if you desire
$$\frac{S_a}{S_\infty}=k$$ for a given $n$ you need to solve for $a$ the equation
$$\Gamma \left(\frac{1}{2 n},2^{-n} a^{2 n}\right)=\Gamma \left(\frac{1}{2 n}\right)-2\,k \,n\, \Gamma \left(1+\frac{1}{2 n}\right)$$ and this will require some numerical method such as Newton. This does not make much problems.

Doing it for $k=0.99$, some results
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & a_n \\
 1 &  2.57583 \\
 2 &  1.76640 \\
 3 &  1.59095 \\
 4 &  1.51900 \\
 5 &  1.48120 \\
 6 &  1.45847 \\
 7 &  1.44360 \\
 8 &  1.43327 \\
 9 &  1.42578 \\
 10 &  1.42017 \\
 11 &  1.41585 \\
 12 &  1.41246 \\
 13 &  1.40975 \\
 14 &  1.40756 \\
 15 &  1.40576 \\
 16 &  1.40427 \\
 17 &  1.40303 \\
 18 &  1.40198 \\
 19 &  1.40109 \\
 20 &  1.40033
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: Ah, I was aware of the incomplete gamma integral. Is there an analytical way to fix the maximum of the super gaussian profile, and also fix the upper and lower ends to ensure that, say, 99% of the area is enclosed within the upper and lower bounds?

Comment: The comment should have said "wasn't aware."